# Replicating Codeigniter's humanize() and underscore() function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to replicate CI's `humanize()` and `underscore()` function in Javascript.

From the [**CI documentation**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/inflector_helper.html), `underscore()` takes multiple words separated by spaces and underscores them while `humanize()` takes multiple words separated by underscores and adds spaces between them. The CI implementation looks something like:

```
function underscore($str) {
    return preg_replace('/[\s]+/', '_', strtolower(trim($str)));
}

function humanize($str) {
    return ucwords(preg_replace('/[_]+/', ' ', strtolower(trim($str))));
}
```

My code doesn't have to replicate the behavior *exactly*, but for the `underscore()` function I'd like it to be able to deal with multiple whitespace characters, while the `humanize()` function can be a bit looser and assume that only one underscore will only be there to separate each word.

So far what I have is:

```
function underscore(string) {
    string = $.trim(string).toLowerCase();
    var oldString;

    while(oldString !== string){
        oldString = string;
        string = string.replace(/\s+/, '_');
    }   
    return string;
}

function humanize(string) {
    string = $.trim(string);
    var terms = string.split('_');

    for(var i=0; i < terms.length; i++){
        terms[i] = terms[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + terms[i].slice(1);
    }

    return terms.join(' ');
}
```

Which works fine, yes, but I don't really like the way I did this (It's *way* too long compared to the PHP. There must be a more compact version), so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient / readable method to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `g` modifier to do the replacement globally as:

```
function underscore(string) {
   string = $.trim(string).toLowerCase();
   return string.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
}
```

Comment: I can't believe how I missed that (now I feel slightly embarrassed at how much code it took to replicate that flag)